# Nested property of entity never saved to database (EF6)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently having some issues with the Entity Framework not saving navigation properties of an Entity to the database when the property has been updated. I have an advertiser class that contains a reference to GoogleAnalyticsProfile, both of which are entities stored in the database and both are accessible through the DataContext.

```
    public class Advertiser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int ConcernId { get; set; }
        public Concern Concern { get; set; }
        public List<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }

        public GoogleAnalyticsProfile GoogleAnalyticsProfile { get; set; }
        public DashboardConfiguration DashboardConfiguration { get; set; }

        public Advertiser()
        {
            GoogleAnalyticsProfile = new GoogleAnalyticsProfile();
            DashboardConfiguration = new DashboardConfiguration();
        }
    }
```

In my model configuration of the Advertiser class I have defined the relationship as follows:

```
HasRequired(a => a.GoogleAnalyticsProfile);
```

And when updating the Entity I use the following code:

```
Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

When selecting an Advertiser I use .Include()s to ensure all required properties are properly loaded into the Advertiser object and this works. However, whenever I attempt to save the Entity back into the database it will nicely update the changed Advertiser but ignore both the GoogleAnalyticsProfile and the DashboardConfiguration properties.

I went home pretty frustrated yesterday as my model was never making it into the database; However, when I first tried today it worked: the changed navigation property was nicely pushed back into the database and subsequent queries returned the proper value. At this moment it is rather dodgy in its behavior: Sometimes it will save the nested property, other times it won't. I set the .Log property to Trace.WriteLine to I do see whenever it updates the entire model or just the advertiser.

My application is written in Asp.net WebApi 2.1 and comes with a side-application that runs as a service to perform certain tasks such as downloading the google analytics data. When testing my web-service I start both applications. Is there a possibility that the EF shares the data context / cache between both applications and thus prevents the profile to be written to the database? There seems to be a relation between the download task running(while holding a reference to the profile) and the update not succeeding.

Thanks

Comment: Is your DbContext static?

Comment: My DbContext isn't static. I do however use Ninject and used `Bind<DbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope()` for my WebApi project and `Bind<DbContext>().ToSelf().InThreadScope()` for the Windows Service.